# Python - how to set default parameter equal to another parameter

Tags: python, default, optional-parameters

I have a function, which should have one optional parameter. I want the optional parameter to be the same as other parameter. Something like this:

```
def foo(arg1, arg2, src, dst=src):
  ...
  ...
```

Parameter `dst` is the optional one. The thing is when `dst` is not given when calling `foo`, it should be same as `src`.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
def foo(arg1, arg2, src, dst=None):
    dst = dst if dst is not None else src
```

Test:

```
>>> def foo(arg1, arg2, src, dst=None):
...     dst = dst if dst is not None else src
...     print dst
... 
>>> foo(0, 0, "test")
test
```

---

Following @TanveerAlam 's comment, I don't want to make assumptions about your arguments (what if `dst` can be `False`?), I did use shorter versions in my original post and I'll leave them here for reference:

```
def foo(arg1, arg2, src, dst=None):
    dst = dst if dst else src
```

Or even:

```
def foo(arg1, arg2, src, dst=None):
    dst = dst or src
```

Note that these versions will prevent values other than `None` in `dst` (like `False`, `[]` ...)

Comment: `dst = dst if dst else src` this would work too as `bool` value of  `None` is `False`.

Comment: I would prefer `dst = dst or src`. A bit more clear and less repetitive, and relies on the same behaviour as `dst if dst else src`